# Create Views depending on the dynamic type of an object returned by the model in MVP

Tags: design, object-oriented, c++, interfaces

In my MVP app, my model (a service) returns a collection of `ISession` pointers. Each pointer points to an object of a derived type `HttpSession` or `HttpsSession`. The model (the service) knows nothing about any GUI, Views, Presenters, etc.

In my Presenter, I need to create and show a View, which should be different depending on the type of the session. How can I do this without using `dynamic_cast` check on the pointers and without making `ISession` -- and thus the model (the service) -- know about the existence of the GUI, MVP, etc.?

*Note:* In general, I have the same problem with writing the sessions' data into DB. The Presenter should call the database manager and it should write the sessions into the DB. But I don't understand how it can differentiate between the two types of the sessions without using the check on the dynamic type of the session. I just decided to choose one of the problems and ask here. Help me, please. I read and read about visitor, strategy, etc. patterns, but still cannot grab how developers normally do it.

Comment: If you need to distinguish these session types, add methods to `ISession` to make them distinguishable. Implementing the visitor pattern is one way to do this, but maybe a `virtual bool is_secure() const = 0` method would be enough. If this is actually about HTTP vs HTTPS, note that nowadays the only reasonable response to a HTTP request is to respond with a permanent redirect to the HTTPS version (with very few exceptions). Such a redirect would typically be handled in a reverse proxy, before the backend with your business logic is reached.

Comment: @amon, thank you for your comment! No, in reality I put here Https and Http just for example. I honestly read that it's nearly the same -- to use an enum or smth like that -- to determine the real dynamic class of a object. That this is bad.

Comment: Typically a Presenter (or Controller) in the MVC or MVP pattern would already know the exact type for each different Model it needs because it would either provide that to its View or convert it into a ViewModel.   So instead of using `ISession` perhaps you could remove inheritance and any relationships between the classes then use separate functions or services for each Model, returning the correct type directly.

Comment: @BenCottrell Thank you for your comment! But the model in my case is a network service which gets a list of sessions (Type1 or Type2 sessions) from network and then the service returns the list to the Presenter and the Presenter would use diffrerent View forms for different types of sessions. So unfortunately, Presenter really does not know the type of each particular session in the returned list of sessions.

Comment: For now, honestly, I am inclined to use the visitor pattern, though I kind don't like it as it seems too complicated. But I am afraid that if I use enums I would get comments like "Having an enum is like throwing a party for all those Open/Closed Principle is for suckers people" from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934107/4781940.

Comment: @JenyaKh Don't use design patterns unless they solve an actual problem. The OCP is a somewhat ill-defined principle, and it doesn't really apply in an internal code base where you can always refactor everything without having to maintain stable APIs or ABIs.

Comment: @amon [ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784389/difference-between-api-and-abi)

Comment: @candied_orange, I'm sorry, I know what abi is (mangling, parameters order, etc.), but I didn't get your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @JenyaKh that's what I'm asking amon.

Comment: @JenyaKh to you I'll ask: what's wrong with session->createView()->show();

Comment: @candied_orange yes, ABI = application binary interface. A change maintains API-compatibility if you can recompile dependent code without changes. A change maintains ABI-compatibility if you can re-link dependent libraries or object files without having to recompile them. This is important in the C/C++ world (and was the motivation for the *original* Open–Closed Principle), but it only really matters for externally consumed libraries, not if you can recompile & redeploy everything yourself.

Comment: @amon so less Ill defined and more misapplied?

Comment: @amon, thank you very much for your comment on abi. I have never thought so deeply on the subject. Your definition and explanation is really valuable.